# Is it possible to prepend and append content to the body of html exports in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have an org document `foo.org`:

```
#+TITLE: Page Title
#+AUTHOR: Me

Hello world!
```

When `foo.org` is exported to `foo.html`, the body is:

```
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1 class="title">Page Title</h1>
<p>
Hello world! 
</p>
</div>
<div id="postamble" class="status">
<p class="author">Author: Me</p>
<p class="date">Created: 2017-08-02 Wed 18:39</p>
<p class="validation"></p>
</div>
</body>
```

I want to prepend and append literal html code to the body of `foo.html`. Is this a feature in `org-mode`? It seems that something like

```
#+TITLE: Page Title
#+AUTHOR: Me
#+HTML_BODY_PREPEND: <prepended html code>
#+HTML_BODY_APPEND: <appended html code>

Hello world!
```

should be exported as

```
<body>
<prepended html code>
<div id="content">
<h1 class="title">Page Title</h1>
<p>
Hello world! 
</p>
</div>
<div id="postamble" class="status">
<p class="author">Author: Me</p>
<p class="date">Created: 2017-08-02 Wed 18:45</p>
<p class="validation"></p>
</div>
<appended html code>
</body>
```